# SQL dynamic-pivot table to asp:Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, pivot-table

**Hello everyone.**

I made a stored-procedure that makes a *pivot* table. 
In asp.net I have an *asp:listview* control that must be equal to this.
I managed to store the table into a *DataTable* in c# code-behind but I can not bind the listview with it and I can not use Eval in the ItemTemplate cause the columns are dynamic (not always the same header).

I tried with LV.datasource = datatable and DataBind() but the LV is empty.

Can someone help me with this? ( I need to show the headers along with the table body). Thanks.

Comment: If you are write the static columns in `asp:listview`  then remove all the columns and try to bind `asp:listview` dynamic.Is your **DataTable** contain data or not while binding?.

Comment: @RaviKantSingh I didn't write anything in LayoutTemplate and yes I fill the datatable and then I try to bind the LV with it

Comment: Add design part of in your  `asp:listview`  question.